Why didn't Bruriah tear kriyah?
In Yalkut Shimoni Mishlei Remez 964 there is a record of Bruriah informing her husband Rebbi Meir of the death of their sons

ד"א אשת חיל מי ימצא. אמרו מעשה היה בר' מאיר שהיה יושב במנחה בשבת ודורש ומתו שני בניו, מה עשתה אמן הניחה שניהם על המטה ופירשה סדין עליהם, במוצאי שבת בא רבי מאיר מבית המדרש אמר לה היכן שני בני, אמרה לו לבית המדרש הלכו, אמרו לה צפיתי בבית המדרש, ולא ראיתים, נתנה לו הכוס של הבדלה והבדיל וחזר, ואמר לה היכן שני בני אמרה לו פעמים שהלכו למקום פלוני ועכשו הם באים, הקריבה לפניו לאכול, לאחר שאכל אמרה לו רבי שאלה יש לי לשאול, א"ל אמ רי שאלתך, אמר לו רבי קודם היום בא אחד ונתן לי פקדון ועכשו בא ליטול אחזיר לו או לאו, אמר לה בתי מי שיש לו פקדון אינו צריך להזיר לרבו, אמרה לו חוץ מדעתך לא הייתי מחזרת אותו, מה עשתה תפשה אותו בידו והעלהו לחדר והקריבה אותו למטה, נטלה הסדין מעליהם וראה שניהם מתים מונחים על המטה, התחיל בוכה ואומר בני בני רבי רבי. בני בדרך ארץ ורבי שהיו מאירין עיני בתורתן, באותה שעה אמרה ליה רבי לא כך אמרת לי שאנו צריכין להחזיר פקדון לרבו, כך ה' נתן וה' לקח יהי שם ה' מבורך, א"ר חנינא בדבר זה נחמתו ונתישבה דעתו לכך נאמר אשת חיל מי ימצא

My question is after Rebbi Meir made havdalah and Shabbat was over didn't Bruriah have an obligation to tear kriyah for the death of her sons right away?
My assumption is that she did not do so, because otherwise wouldn't that have indicated to Rebbi Meir that she was mourning?

Perhaps she held that shabbat ended later than her husband held?

Halichipedia says:

Ideally a person should tear kriyah immediately or as soon as possible
after the person dies or he hears about it. The Sephardic minhag,
however, is to tear kriyah after the burial or before the seudat
havrah. This minhag has what to rely upon. Note: Chazon Ovadia
(Aveilut v. 1 p. 226) writes that the Sephardic minhag to tear kriyah
after the burial has what to rely upon. Rav Mordechai Eliyahu's
comment on Kitzur S”A 195:2 confirms this minhag.

So one possibility is that Rebbi Meir's wife held like the  Sephardic minhag.
Another possibility is based on the idea (don't have a source now) that the tearing is done when the grief is most intense.  Rebbi Meir's wife's grief was not at its height until she told her husband.
